# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException with value {3D} in URL query

Tags: jmeter, urlencode, query-string

My Get Request has query value `{3D}` in the url when i make request using this it throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException same request works fine in browser and postman

I tried to provide sample URL for debugging by there is no URl with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have either `{` or `}` in the URL path section without [encoding](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP) so the options are in:

1. Use [__urlencode() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__urlencode) like:

   ```
   ${__urlencode({3D})}
   ```

   [image]
2. Or put your query under "Parameters" tab of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request)  and tick `URL Encode?` box

   [image]

In general if the request works in browser or postman you can just record the request using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

- [Instructions for browser](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html)
- [Instructions for postman](https://www.blazemeter.com/how-to-convert-your-postman-api-tests-to-jmeter-for-scaling/)

Answer (score 1):

In query you need to encode the `{}` signs, send instead encoded value:

```
%7BD%7D
```

Or use [urlencode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__urlencode) function

```
${__urlencode({D})}
```